# How to check user's role after login in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im trying to check for user's role after login(Devise), so in user model, i have to `role`: student and teacher

my `user` model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum role: {student: 0, teacher: 1}

  belongs_to :user
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  has_many :posts

  after_initialize do
  if self.new_record?
    self.role ||= :student
  end
end
end
```

so now in `my application.html.erb` i want to check and display different navbar based on different user roles:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
<% if teacher? %>
<!-- show navbar for teacher -->
<% else %>
<!-- show navbar for student -->
<% end %>
<% else %>
<!-- show login/reg buttons -->
<% end %>
```

and here's my `application` controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  helper_method :teacher? , :student?

  def teacher?
      current_user.role = User.where(role: [:teacher])
  end

  def student?
    current_user.role = User.where(role: [:student])
  end

  protected
    def configure_permitted_parameters
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:name])
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:name])
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Your methods `ApplicationController#teacher?` and `ApplicationController#student?` are really bad, remove them and use built-in `User#teacher?` or `User#student?` instead:

```
<% if current_user.teacher? %>
```

BTW, you also don't need this `after_initialize` hack you're using for setting default value to `student` - it's enough to set the default value of the `role` column in db to `0`.

Also, as turned out, you have to add `role` to `devise_permitted_parameters` so you can update its value from within devise controllers:

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: %i[name role])
  # ...
end
```

Comment: `<% if current_user.teacher? %>` doesn't work, i dont know why

Comment: @catlover69 what are the symptoms? Are you getting an error?

Comment: So how do you know it's not working? Does it show 'student' version for 'teacher' user? Please be a little bit more specific.

Comment: It's not showing the correct navbar based on the `<% if %>`, for example when i wrote: `<% if current_user.teacher? %> navbar for teacher <% else %> navbar for student <% end %>` no matter what user role im logined to, the navbar is the same or only show one of the navbar(student or teacher navbar) for both user roles

Comment: Are you sure your `User` records have proper roles? You can quite easily debug this by putting `<%= current_user.role %>` above `<% if current_user.teacher? %>` line, this way you'll see what's the actual role of currectly signed in user.

Comment: Undefined method `role` for nil:NilClass

Comment: Yeah, put it above `<% if current_user.teacher? %>` but below `<% if user_signed_in? %>` line, otherwise if you're not signed in, you get this error.

Comment: Do you have a user signed in?

Comment: "Still not working" you mean you still get an error? Even if you put this below `<% if user_signed_in? %>` line?

Comment: Yes, the user will be assigned a `role` based on their choice, i put this `<%= f.select :role, collection: User.roles.keys.to_a %>` in devise/registrations/new.html.erb

Comment: Did you add `role` to devise permitted parameters?

Comment: I already have a `devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:name])`, so do I edit this one or add a second line of `devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: %i[name role])`?

Comment: You have to edit this line to look like as I wrote it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `role` attribute as a permitted parameter to devise. You can do so like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:role])
  end
end
```

Keep in mind, this is only for signup. If you need it for signin and/or update, you'll have to add those also. You can find more information here: [Devise 4 Strong Parameters](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters). If you are using Devise below version 4, you can see the docs here: [Devise < 4 Strong Parameters](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/tree/3-stable#strong-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

Use Render Method in your controller action. In my case

```
if current_user.role == 'student'
      render 'dashboard/teacher'
end
```

Comment: Hi Khajan. Welcome to StackOverflow. Perhaps it will be more helpful if you tell while file exactly the render method goes (in the template for example).